# How to use options API along with Composition API in vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

vue3 + vite2

Very simple code as below. 
Expect: when click on button, change reactive msg variable. 
it works expectly when development(vite), after build production(vite build) and deploy,
it seem cannot work, click method cannot access reactive msg variable. 
From vuejs document, options API can work along with composition API.

```
<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <button @click="click">Click</button>
</template>

<script setup>
  const msg = ref('hello')      
</script>

<script>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  export default {   
    methods: {
      click() {
        this.msg = 'ok'     
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can combine options and composition api if you return values, methods from setup function:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const msg = ref('hello')
    const changeMsg = () => {
      return 'again'
    }
    return { msg, changeMsg }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      otherMsg: this.changeMsg()
    }
  },
  methods: {
    click() {
      this.msg = 'ok'     
    },
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
  <h1>{{ otherMsg }}</h1>
  <button @click="click">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So basically whatever the `setup` function returns acts like what we used to return in `data()` in Vue 2.x?

Comment: @connexo Not just `data()` you also have to return `methods` from `setup()` or use `<script setup>` in Single File Components.

Comment: how can you call `click()` from the `setup` section?

Comment: @mga hey mate, You can not , it is one way road, so You can only use data function properties, computed , methods from options api, not other way around